# Making a Python script executable chmod755?

Tags: python, hosting

My hosting provider says my python script must be made to be executable(chmod755).  What does this mean & how do I do it?

Cheers!

Comment: It means "readable and executable by everybody, writable by owner only". If you have shell access, @Jian Lin's answer is fine; else, maybe your provider leaves permission bits intact on uploads (in which case you need to set them before uploading) -- if neither applies your provider must document how to set permission bits for their particular setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have ssh access to your web space, connect and issue

```
chmod 755 nameofyourscript.py
```

If you do not have ssh access but rather connect by FTP, check your FTP application to see whether it supports setting the permissions.

As to the meaning of 755:

- first digit is user settings (yourself)
- second digit is group settings
- third digit is the rest of the system

The digits are constructed by adding the permision values. 1 = executable, 2 = writable and 4 = readable. I.e. 755 means that you yourself can read, write and execute the file and everybody else can read and execute it.

Answer (score 5):

Unix-like systems have "file modes" that say who can read/write/execute a file. The mode 755 means owner can read/write/execute, and everyone else can read/execute but not write. To make your Python script have this mode, you type

```
chmod 0755 script.py
```

You also need a shebang like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

on the very first line of the file to tell the operating system what kind of script it is.

Answer (score 1):

It means, that somebody (the user, a group or everybody) has the right so execute (or read or write) the script (or a file in general).

The permissions are expressed in different ways:

```
$ chmod +x file.py # makes it executable by anyone
$ chmod +w file.py # makes it writeabel by anyone
$ chmod +r file.py # makes it readably by anyone

$ chmod u+x file.py # makes it executable for the owner (user) of the file
$ chmod g+x file.py # makes it executable for the group (of the file)
$ chmod o+x file.py # makes it executable for the others (everybody)
```

You can take away permissions in the same way, just substitute the `+` by a `-`

```
$ chmod o-x file.py # makes a file non-executable for the others (everybody)
$ ...
```

Octal numbers express the same in a different way.
4 is reading, 2 writing, 1 execution.

simple math:

```
read + execute = 5
read + write + execute = 7
execute + write = 3
...
```

packed all in one short and sweet command:

```
# 1st digit: user permissions
# 2nd digit: group permissions
# 3rd digit: 'other' permissions

# add the owner all perms., 
# the group and other only write and execution

$ chmod 755 file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

on the shell (such as bash), just type

```
chmod 755 file.py
```

to make it executable.  You can use

```
ls -l file.py
```

to verify the execution permission is set (the "x" in "rwxr-xr-x")

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other fine answers here, you should be aware that most FTP clients have a `chmod` command to allow you to set permissions on files at the server. You may not need this if permissions come across properly, but there's a good chance they do not.